# How to delete a certain part of a list in sqlite3 python?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am making a program where you can edit a part of the list using sqlite3, tkinter and python. However, there is this part of the program that keeps bugging me.

```
cursor.execute('DELETE FROM Photos phonenumber WHERE name1=?', [entry.get()])
```

With that line of code I am trying to delete a certain part of the list, so I can replace with something else in the future. An error keeps showing up, saying that there is a syntax error near phonenumber. If anyone knows that proper sqlite3 command to delete specific parts of a program, that would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Jamal

Comment: Is the table name photos or phonenumber? You can only delete rows from one table

Comment: The table name is photos. The part of the table I want to delete is phonenumber

Comment: Then you don't want `DELETE` as it deletes whole row(s). You want to `UPDATE` a row and overwrite the phone number with an empty string or `NULL`.

Comment: what is the update code?

Comment: See the [docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html)

Comment: Thank you so much, If you post your answer I will check it as correct

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the update sqlite3 function.

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html